# How to make child communicate with parent in this scenario react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a quiz app. Currently i can switch to the next question by answering (clicking a button). Also, when timer expires (10 secs for each question) it automatically switches to the next question (`timer` resets to default state) regardless of button clicked or no. Above mentioned things works and its fine.

**However** I made a timer as a seperate child component to avoid unneccesary rerenders of parent component. The problem is that when i click a button to answer the question `timer` does not reset (but it should) to its default state value (10secs). I dont know how to communicate between child (Timer) and parent component (App), because i dont wanna initialize that `timer` state in parent component and put it in `handleAnswerCorrectness` so when `currentPage` changes i also reset `timer`, because it would cause parent rerender each second and lose sense of making it a child component.

How to do it properly???

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const questions = [
  {
    questionText: "What is the capital city of France",
    answerOptions: [
      { id: 1, answerText: "New York", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 2, answerText: "London", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 3, answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: true },
      { id: 4, answerText: "Dublin", isCorrect: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    questionText: "Who is CEO of Tesla?",
    answerOptions: [
      { id: 1, answerText: "Jeff Bezos", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 2, answerText: "Elon Musk", isCorrect: true },
      { id: 3, answerText: "Bill Gates", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 4, answerText: "Tony Stark", isCorrect: false }
    ]
  }
];

const App = () =>  {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

  const handleAnswerCorrectness = () => {
    if (currentPage + 1 < questions.length) {
      setCurrentPage((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Question {currentPage + 1}/{questions.length}
        </h3>
        <Timer
          currentPage={currentPage}
          onCurrentPageChange={setCurrentPage}
          questionsLenght={questions.length}
        />
      </div>
      <p>{questions[currentPage].questionText}</p>
      <div>
        {questions[currentPage].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
          <button key={answerOption.id}  onClick={handleAnswerCorrectness}>
            {answerOption.answerText}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Timer = ({
  onCurrentPageChange,
  currentPage,
  questionsLenght
}) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timer > 0) {
        setTimer((prevState) => prevState - 1);
      }
      if (timer === 0 && currentPage + 1 < questionsLenght) {
        onCurrentPageChange((prevState) => prevState + 1);
        setTimer(10);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{timer}</span>
    </div>
  );
};


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: its better to use a React context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this purpose, or better a state manager like redux.

Comment: Try updating your array of dependencies to `[currentPage, onCurrentPageChange, questionsLenght, timer]`

Comment: That wont change anything @AndrewShearer

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848967/refreshing-children-state-from-parent-react answer your question?

Comment: "I made a timer as a seperate child component to avoid unneccesary rerenders of parent component" <- in general, do not worry about "unnecessary rerenders" until you can measure and are confident they are causing issues. Complicating components and logic is likely a worse outcome than re-rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `useEffect` in `Timer` is both setting state `timer` and reading it in dependencies array, which could cause a conflict.

Perhaps try separating it to 2 `useEffect` with more simple logic, so related code will only run when needed.

One for the purpose of countdown, and reset `timer` when `currentPage` changes:

```
// Countdown effect
useEffect(() => {
  setTimer(10);
  const interval = setInterval(
    () =>
      setTimer((prevState) => {
        if (prevState > 0) return prevState - 1;
        return prevState;
      }),
    1000
  );

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [currentPage]);
```

Another to handle timeout and trigger `onCurrentPageChange`:

```
// Timeout effect
useEffect(() => {
  if (timer === 0 && currentPage + 1 < questionsLenght)
    onCurrentPageChange((prevState) => prevState + 1);
}, [timer, currentPage, questionsLenght]);
```

There might be other issues that needed to be addressed, but hopefully this would still help by making the logic cleaner.

Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const questions = [
  {
    questionText: "What is the capital city of France",
    answerOptions: [
      { id: 1, answerText: "New York", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 2, answerText: "London", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 3, answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: true },
      { id: 4, answerText: "Dublin", isCorrect: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    questionText: "Who is CEO of Tesla?",
    answerOptions: [
      { id: 1, answerText: "Jeff Bezos", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 2, answerText: "Elon Musk", isCorrect: true },
      { id: 3, answerText: "Bill Gates", isCorrect: false },
      { id: 4, answerText: "Tony Stark", isCorrect: false },
    ],
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

  const handleAnswerCorrectness = () => {
    if (currentPage + 1 < questions.length) {
      setCurrentPage((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Question {currentPage + 1}/{questions.length}
        </h3>
        <Timer
          currentPage={currentPage}
          onCurrentPageChange={setCurrentPage}
          questionsLenght={questions.length}
        />
      </div>
      <p>{questions[currentPage].questionText}</p>
      <div>
        {questions[currentPage].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
          <button key={answerOption.id} onClick={handleAnswerCorrectness}>
            {answerOption.answerText}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Timer = ({ onCurrentPageChange, currentPage, questionsLenght }) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);

  // Countdown effect
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(10);
    const interval = setInterval(
      () =>
        setTimer((prevState) => {
          if (prevState > 0) return prevState - 1;
          return prevState;
        }),
      1000
    );

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [currentPage]);

  // Timeout effect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0 && currentPage + 1 < questionsLenght)
      onCurrentPageChange((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, [timer, currentPage, questionsLenght]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{timer}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```